# Strange error using "input" in Python

Tags: python

I was just trying to use `raw_input` in a python program when I got this strange message.

The program:

```
message = input("Want to see something?")
```

The output:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'raw_input'
```

Any help would make me very happy.

Comment: Is that one line the _entire_ program?

Comment: can you add your actual code?

Comment: Im only getting the error from one line.

Comment: @Conner Restart your interpreter and try that line again, then.

Comment: NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined @senshin

Comment: @Conner See the answer below. There is no `raw_input` function in Python 3. Hell if I know why you were getting an `AttributeError` the first time, though.

Comment: I don't believe that running that line of code produced that error. You'd have to do some pretty tricky stuff to make that happen.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged "encryption"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on your version of Python. If you're using Python 2, you should use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

```
>>> raw_input("Want to see something? ")
Want to see something? Yeah!
'Yeah!'
```

As in Python 3, you should use [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input):

```
>>> raw_input("Want to see something? ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
>>> input("Want to see something? ")
Want to see something? Yeah!
'Yeah!'
```

As you can see in the documentation, both do the exact same thing, just the name changed.